# ngStyle dynamic variable error ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'ngStyleSmall'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having 2 variable's for `ngstyle`

```
ngStyleSmall = {
        width: '150px !important',
        'max-width': '150px',
    };

    ngStylemedium = {
        width: '250px !important',
        'max-width': '400px',
    };

ls_style:string
ls_style="ngStyleSmall" // will be bringing from database
```

```html
<mat-form-field [ngStyle]="ls_style">  
     <input  [(ngModel)]="code" name="code"  matInput placeholder="Co."> 
</mat-form-field>
```

In html ng model i want to assign variable dynamically, how its possible?

Comment: Hello shiji, thank you for your question. Could you please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve? "In html ng model i want to assign variable dynamically" -> What variable and why do you want to assign it?

Comment: improved readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you should put value of ngStyleSmall into ls_style try:

```
this.ls_style = this["ngStyleSmall"];
```

see [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-k7dpzj).